# how to pass json in query string parameter with jquery $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, getjson

Jquery $.get should send single query string parameter  _filters whose value is json string:

```
API/MyGet?_filters='{groupOp:"AND",rules:[{field:"Toode",op:"eq",data:"xxxx"}]}'&sort=code
```

I tried

```
$.get( 'API/MyGet',  {
   _filters:{ groupOp:"AND",
              rules:[{field:"Toode", op:"eq", data:'xxxx'}]
            },
   sort: 'code'
   },
   function(data) {
            alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
   }
   );
```

but Chrome developer tools show that this creates incorrect and strange query string:

```
_filters[groupOp]=AND&_filters[rules][0][field]=Toode&_filters[rules][0][op]=eq&_filters[rules][0][data]=
```

How to force jquery get to pass proper query string ?

Comment: Do you really need that "`_filters`" object? `$.get( 'API/Entity/ToodeL',  {
    groupOp:"AND",
              rules:[{field:"Toode", op:"eq", data:'xxxx'}]
            }`

Comment: Yes. In real app query string has more parameters: page number, page size, sort order etc. _filters can contain more sophisticated search condition. So _filters must be single parameters whose value is json string.

Comment: @Developer I modified question. Added sort parameter also and changed _filters value to string

Comment: I might be wrong, but IMO the query string which is getting constructed in this is the way it should be. Could you please mention the format of query string you expect?

Comment: Short: you can't. This query string is generated by the `$.serialize()` method. You would need to extend the functionality of this method -or pre-process the query sting yourself i.e. `$.get('path/to', 'filters={jsonstring}');`

Comment: Also, the query string generated is somewhat standard -most servers would not expect json encoded variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var params = {
  sort: '...',
  _filters: JSON.stringify({
    'key': 'value'
  })
};

$.get('API/MyGet', params, function(data) {
  alert( JSON.stringify(data) );
});
```